# Find Multiple Selected ListView Item Indices in UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `ListView` named `sandwichToppings` which displays various sandwich toppings and allows the user to select multiple. In my controller code, I must capture the selected toppings by their index in the `ListView`, and send those indices back using an array.

The code which causes me to stumble is visible below. I have not been able to figure out the part which captures one or more toppings to the sandwich (the rest works fine).

```
  void readSandwichSelection()
  {
     int[] toppings = null;

     // One or many toppings were added to the sandwich.
     if(toppingsAvailable.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
     {
        toppings = new int[toppingsAvailable.SelectedItems.Count];
        int toppingIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < toppingsAvailable.Items.Count; i++)
        {
           ListViewItem test = (ListViewItem)toppingsAvailable.Items.ElementAt(i);
           if(test.IsSelected == true)
           {
              toppings[toppingIndex] = i;
              toppingIndex++;
           }
        }
     }
     // No sandwich topping.
     else
     {
        order.addSandwich(sandwichesAvailable.SelectedIndex + 1);
     }
  }
```

Along my journey, I have tried a couple solutions found on Telerik. The first:

```
  foreach (ListViewDataItem item in radListView1.SelectedItems)
  {
      int example = radListView1.Items.IndexOf(item);
  }
```

The above example fails to work because

1. `ListViewDataItem` does not exist.
2. When replaced by `ListViewItem`, a run-time error occurs: ***System.InvalidCastException:** 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem'.'*

The second attempted solution:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < radListView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (this.radListView1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            int example = i;
        }
    }
```

This solution cannot work because the `.Selected` property simply does not exist.

In all my hour of attempted work, I come up with either of these two problems. Either some form of cast exception occurs, or it is impossible to reach the property.

In my example above, I did have success in reaching the `isSelected` property by making a copy of each list item, and testing whether it had been selected. However, although Visual Studio lets me make the assignment

`ListViewItem test = (ListViewItem)toppingsAvailable.Items.ElementAt(i);`

this statement cannot run at compile time, causing an error as written previously. Which datatype other than `ListViewItem` must be used to count over list view items?

`toppingsAvailable.SelectedItems` will return a `List<>` of selected items. However, how could I know from this list which list index selected items belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to get the selected toppings's indexes and put the indexes in an array. The indexes will be saved in the `ToppingArray`.

```
void readSandwichSelection()
{
    int[] ToppingArray = new int[toppingsAvailable.SelectedItems.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < toppingsAvailable.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        var selectedIndex = toppingsAvailable.Items.IndexOf(toppingsAvailable.SelectedItems[i]);
        ToppingArray[i] = selectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. It is `Selected` rather than `IsSelected`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < toppingsAvailable.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var test = toppingsAvailable.Items[i];
    if (test.Selected)
    {
        toppings[toppingIndex] = i;
        toppingIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio only allows `ContentTemplateSelector` or `IsSelected` as properties that exist for that object.

This does not solve the runtime error.

Comment: Is toppingsAvailable a `System.Windows.Forms.ListView`? See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: as specified in the tags, this is a UWP project.